# Search in Json column with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, laravel-5

In my emails table, I have a column named `To` with column-type `Json`. This is how values are stored:

```
[
    {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Test", 
            "address": "test@example.com"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Test 2", 
            "address": "test2@example.com"
        }
    }
]
```

Now I want a collection of all emails sent to "test@example.com". I tried:

```
DB::table('emails')->whereJsonContains('to->emailAddress->address', 'test@example.com')->get();
```

(see https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#json-where-clauses)
but I do not get a match. Is there a better way to search using Laravel (Eloquent)?

In the debugbar, I can see that this query is "translated" as:

```
select * from `emails` where json_contains(`to`->'$."emailAddress"."address"', '\"test@example.com\"'))
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: database = MySQL 5.7.24

Comment: it works when there is only 1 email address

Comment: This can help if you have a multilingual slug. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71766061/13779574

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The arrow operator doesn't work in arrays. Use this instead:

```
DB::table('emails')
   ->whereJsonContains('to', [['emailAddress' => ['address' => 'test@example.com']]])
   ->get()
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a wild card? For example, `Activity::whereJsonContains('properties', 'like', ['name' => "%$query%"])->get();`

Comment: @EvanLalo No, MySQL doesn't support that.

Comment: Hi, its working fine,  can you share reference document.

Answer (score 16):

I haven't used the json column but as the documentation refers, the below code should work fine.

```
DB::table('emails')
  ->where('to->emailAddresss->address','test@example.com')
  ->get();
```

Comment: I've tried with `->where` and with `->whereJsonContains`, but no luck ..

Comment: Can you include your table schema so we have better knowledge of the table.

Comment: Pretty sure it's `->where('to->"$.emailAddresss.address"','test@example.com')`

Comment: @Tofandel where I find documentation of that, I have spent hours trying to search for a value that is in an array that is in the json.

Answer (score 8):

In case to store array in json format. And just have an array list of IDs, I did this.

> items is the column name and $item_id is the term I search for

```
// $item_id = 2
// items = '["2","7","14","1"]'
$menus = Menu::whereJsonContains('items', $item_id)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the Laravel API docs for the `whereJsonContains` method
https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereJsonContains

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.

Answer (score 1):

Using Eloquent => Email::where('to->emailAddress->address','test@example.com')->get();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to Where conditions on JSON columns

```
Model::whereJsonContains('coulmn_name->key_from_json', value_from_json)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use where clause with like condition

```
DB::table('emails')->where('To','like','%test@example.com%')->get();
```

Alternatively, if you have Model mapped to emails table names as Email using Eloquent

```
Email::where('To','like','%test@example.com%')->get();
```

Comment: He is talking about json column. I think you are wrong

Comment: There will be problems if there is a address like 11test@example.com for example because it will be found too. 
So it will work, but it's not the best choice.