# Laravel 8.x Where Json Search In Array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

My DB column field ("colors") contains an array structured like this:

```
["1","2","3"]
```

My current query look like this, simplified for better example:

```php
$value = '1';

$cards = Card::query()
->where('colors', 'like', '%' . $value . '%')
->get();
```

The problem is, it fetches data from other columns, for example `["5","8","13"]` will match `"13"` instead of the strict `$value`, which should be `"1"`.

How do I write this query the correct way?

Comment: have you tried `whereJsonContains('colors', 1)`?  assuming this is actually a json column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

used [whereJsonContains](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses) Method here

value like this then do like that ["1","2","3"]

```
$cards = Card::query()
->whereJsonContains('colors', '1')
->get();
```

if value like that [1,2,3] then used like that

```
$cards = Card::query()
    ->whereJsonContains('colors', 1)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can match it along with the quotes

```
$cards = Card::query()
->where('colors', 'like', '%"' . $value . '"%')
->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, this works as well, thought I prefer the json approach since it is indeed a json column.

Comment: Yeah :) should also be faster than `like` I assume

Answer (score 0):

You can query the JSON array fields as follows

```
$cards = Card::query()
->whereNotNull("colors->$value")
->get();
```

The above query will return cards having colour in the `$value`

Answer (score 0):

I had a multilingual Slug. I got it with this code

```
$category = CategoryModel::query()->whereJsonContains('slug->' . app()->getLocale(), $category)->first();
dd($category->toArray());
```

Result:
[image]

DB [image]