# Best way to store and load JSON from database in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-schema-builder

I'm trying to store json into a db and load it back

I tried to store

```
{name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York"}
```

It stored correctly. I checked the db, it showed correctly.

> {name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York"}

I kept getting on the view

```
"{name: \"John\", age: 31, city: \"New York\"}"
```

This is my code.

```
public function store()
{

    $paste             = new Paste;
    $paste->uuid       = Str::uuid()->toString();
    $paste->data       = trim(Request::get('data',''));
    $paste->save();

    return Redirect::to('/paste/'.$paste->uuid)->with('success', 'Created');

}

public function show($uuid)
{
    $paste  = Paste::where('uuid',$uuid)->first();
    return response()->json($paste->data);
}
```

Any hints for me ?

Reproducible here

https://www.bunlongheng.com/paste

---

## Try # 2

If I did this

```
public function show($uuid)
{


    $paste  = Paste::where('uuid',$uuid)->first();
    return View::make('layouts.fe.pastes.show', get_defined_vars());

}
```

and in my view, I only have this 1 line

```
{!!$paste->data!!}
```

I get the same data as what I submitted now.

```
{name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York"}
```

BUT the browser detected it as text, not a response JSON which defeated the purpose of what I am trying to do.

---

## Try # 3

```
public function show($uuid)
{
    $paste  = Paste::where('uuid',$uuid)->first();
    return response()->json(stripslashes($paste->data));
    
}
```

result

```
"{name: \"John\", age: 31, city: \"New York\"}"
```

---

## Try # 4

```
public function show($uuid)
{
    $paste  = Paste::where('uuid',$uuid)->first();
    return View::make('layouts.fe.pastes.show', get_defined_vars());
}
```

view

```
{{ json_encode($paste->data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) }}
```

result

```
"{name: \"John\", age: 31, city: \"New York\"}"
```

---

## Try #5

I think the issue is lying on the storing ... not the loading and rendering.

I tried

```
return response()->json($paste);
```

My JSON parser detected it ...

[image]

```
{
"id": 11,
"status": 0,
"uuid": "0c40f97d-7d98-42c6-864e-71d3ed81eed3",
"name": "n6ou",
"password": "",
"expiration": "",
"type": "json",
"data": "{name: \"John\", age: 31, city: \"New York\"}",
"created_at": "2021-04-22T22:53:11.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-04-22T22:53:11.000000Z"
}
```

This is what I used to store

```
$paste->data       = trim(Request::get('data',''));
$paste->save();
```

---

## Try #6

For those of you that doubt my data/content

I've tried pasting the same line in Pastebin

[image]

It's cleaned, you can see below.

https://pastebin.com/raw/r9akUK1v

Comment: Try using `return response()->json(stripslashes($paste->data));`

Comment: Or, in your view try this:  `{ json_encode($paste->data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) }`

Comment: Try both , slash still there.

Comment: try `{ json_decode($paste->data) }` , this should work.

Comment: what is the controller code look like ?

Comment: Well you already have `response()->json($paste->data);` using `->json()` which should properly encode the JSON which is why you are ending up with `\"`. `json_decode()` in the view should solve that

Comment: https://www.bunlongheng.com/paste -- please try. I uploaded your code.

Comment: `return response()->json($paste->data);` && `{{ json_decode($paste->data) }}`

Comment: I meant in your view do this: `{{ json_decode($paste->data) }}`, this is fine: `return response()->json($paste->data);`

Comment: That’s exactly what I did.

Comment: Are you using blade as the templating engine?

Comment: Yes. I am. Using blade engine

Comment: Hm. Well, I guess you can also try this, just for a test: `$data = json_decode($paste->data)`, then  `return view::make('layouts.fe.pastes.show',$data)` or `return response()->json($data);` but I think this latter will not work since it would be decoding and then encoding again, but it's worth a try

Comment: I think the issue is lying on the storing ... not the loading and rendering.

Comment: Look at my try # 5

Comment: Then maybe try this: `$paste->data = trim(json_encode(Request::get('data',''), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));` before the `$paste->save();`

Comment: Ok doing that now...

Comment: doing that getting `"\"{name:\\\"John\\\", age:31,city:\\\"New York\\\"}\""`

Comment: `$paste->data       = trim(json_encode(Request::get('data',''), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));` & `return response()->json($paste->data);`

Comment: try doing an echo of `$paste->data` after getting the data and before showing in the view. Also add a `die()` after that, maybe that will help isolate the problem. the `->json()` method seems to be escaping the `"` characters in your JSON string, so I'm not sure it's the storing that's the problem, but I'm not sure. It's hard for me to debug just by thinking about it :)

Comment: Try that yourself on your end, if you have time, I want to get this working. I'm very curioys.

Comment: I even tried, `return response()->json(str_replace('\\','',$paste->data));` and it's the slash is still there, it's like haunted me haha.

Comment: Yeah, I can imagine. It's probably something simple. I don't have a Laravel set up on my side. Don't have the time to go through that now to make an example. Maybe later. What you should confirm is what does the string look like in the DB by somehow echoing that value. In my opinion it should be easiest to `echo $paste->data; die();` That should show you if the string is escaped in the DB or the `->json()` method does that which is what I think is happening. But I could be wrong.

Comment: did you try storing like `{name: 'John', age: 31, city: 'New York'}` with single quotation?

Comment: @Psycho Why did u ask that ? I would like to store whatever users provided in the input text area, and return whatever they entered.

Comment: @Psycho Do you think I should use some kind of normalization.

Comment: @Psycho I’m not sure if you know. I used to use a site name myjson.com , somehow they took it down. I want to mimic that. Able to share a JSON with someone very quickly

Comment: I know this has already been answered, but I want to share the [**documentation**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-json) where it states and explains a little more about this so everyone knows where to go first and don't lose time

Comment: This can help if you have a multilingual slug. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71766061/13779574

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Database

In your database migrations add:

```
$table->json('data'); // Recommended. Supported in MySQL since version 5.7.8
```

or

```
$table->text('data');
```

The JSON column type is recommended as it allows you to do SQL queries on JSON data. See [MySQL JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html)

### Model: Casting the Attribute

The next issue is that you need to be able to cast your data into a PHP array.

This is done by modifying the casts attribute in the model:

```
class Paste extends Model {
    protected $casts = [
        'data' => 'array'
    ];
}
```

See [Array and JSON Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) for more information.

Now you can save data onto the attribute as a PHP array, and also assign it a PHP array.

```
 $paste = Paste::first();
 dump($paste); // Returns a PHP array     

 $paste->data = ['some-data' => 20, 'score' => 500];
 $paste->save();
```

Internally, when it saves the data, it automatically would convert it into a JSON string and save it in the database in the correct format.

### Store Method

When taking in input as JSON, it highly depends in how you want to pass the data,

**1. Sending form data with JSON content type (recommended)**

My recommendation is to send the entire data as JSON in the POST body like so:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Body:
{
   "data": {
      "name": "John",
      "age": 31,
      "city": "New York"
   },
   "someOtherField": "Hello!"
}
```

Your `store()` method should now be (I've also added validation code):

```
public function store()
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'data' => ['required', 'array'],
        'data.*.name' => ['required', 'string'],
        'data.*.age' => ['required', 'int'],
        'data.*.city' => ['required', 'string'],
    ]);
    
    $paste = new Paste();
    $paste->uuid = Str::uuid()->toString();
    $paste->data = $request->post('data'); // No need to decode as it's already an array
    $paste->save();

    return Redirect::to("/paste/{$paste->uuid}")
        ->with('success', 'Created');
}
```

**2. Sending form data with form params**

If however you insist in sending data through query params or form params, note these can only send strings. Therefore you need to send an encoded version of the JSON string to persists data types, as follows:

```
Form Params:
- data: '{"name": "John", "age": 31, "city": "New York"}'
- someOtherField: "Hello!"
```

The store method will now look like this:

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'data' => ['required', 'json'], // I'm unsure if data is required
    ]);
    
    $data = json_decode($request->post('data'), true, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR); // Needs to be decoded
    
    // validate $data is correct
    Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string'],
        'age' => ['required', 'int'],
        'city' => ['required', 'string'],
    ])->validate();
    
    
    $paste = new Paste();
    $paste->uuid = Str::uuid()->toString();
    $paste->data = $data;
    $paste->save();

    return Redirect::to("/paste/{$paste->uuid}")
        ->with('success', 'Created');
```

### Show Method

Your show method needs no changes:

```
public function show($uuid)
{
    $paste = Paste::where('uuid', $uuid)->first();
    return response()->json($paste->data);
}
```

Comment: This line, `$data = json_decode($request->post('data'));` kept turning my data input json as null.

Comment: How are you calling your API. Perhaps show your JavaScript or curl code?

Comment: If your using query strings it would be `$request->query('data')`.

Comment: I've update the line. Made a small mistake in not putting true as the 2nd parameter. It will not also throw an error if the data is not a valid JSON string.

Answer (score 4):

1- Your column need to be of type json type

```
$table->json('data');
```

2- in your Model you need to cast your column to an array

```
  protected $casts = ['data' => 'array'];
```

3- sending data value to your controller must be an array so you can use array Laravel validation on it:

```
[
  'data' => 'required|array',
  'data.*.name' => 'required'
   ....
]
```

4- when you store your data it will be parsed automatically and the same when you retrieve your data column it will be converted to an array

Comment: Let me try that suggestion

Comment: I think this method is the best way to work with JSON. One addition (assuming OP is using a MySQL DB): Older MySQL servers don"t support the JSON type. So MySQL <= 5.7 should use LONGTEXT instead.

Comment: @GordonFreeman Sure for old versions, longText is the solution, but I'm not sure about elequont in this case

Comment: @PsyLogic Eloquent handles this just fine. Had no issues with older projects. `protected $casts` does the magic regardless of the actual DB field type. The only drawback I can think of, it would not be possible to benefit from the JSON type field on DB level (search in the JSON, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, but sure it will not work for search since JSON methods added to 5.7+, so you need to use a custom function in ur DB or returning the column value and do the search in ur backend (which is not recommended)

Answer (score 2):

1. Using `->json()` as the migration method to store JSON data (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-json)
2. Refer to "Array & JSON Casting" (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) for how do you prepare the data

I know the answer is not in paragraphs as others, but I like to make it simple and straight. Is it the best solution? No one can tell you that nor prove that? Is this method going to work, no one can tell you that nor prove that, but at least it boosts up your success rate. Let me know if there is anything else I could help with! Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store data as json on DB and restore it just do the following (I always use this way):

1- Add your data to array:

```
$data["name"] = "John";
$data["age"] = 31;
$data["city"] = "New York";
```

2- Encode the array and add it to the database (you can store it as text)

```
$encodedData = json_encode($data);
```

3- If you want to add nested json data just make your array nested array.

4- When you restore the data just use **json_decode** to decode it

Comment: I have to store base on user provided ... please read my post

Comment: Sorry, I give you this way because you said that the problem is on storing.

Json data that came from request have no problem by default but if the problem still exist you can use it to fill the response data to the view

Comment: user will provide json text.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your Model.

```
protected $casts = [
    'data' => 'object'
];
```

Then you can get in your view like this:

```
{{ $data->data->name }}
```