# How to check the json value is not equal to param in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I want to get only those records from DB which not equal to "My Msg".

My DB column is having the JSON like this:

```
`{
   "msg": "My Msg",
   "resource_id": "Resourse"
 }`
```

I tried `JSON_EXTRACT` and `whereJsonContains`

But no luck, I am using Laravel 8 with MySQL.

Query is:

```php
$records = DB::table('atble')->select('res_id',
'msg_string')->where('res_id',
$param)->whereJsonContains('ret_string->msg', 
['elem1','elem2'...])->latest()->first();
```

The above query is not giving me any results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the type of the column in database? is it JSON?

Comment: @SibiKandathil, Yes it is JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to try this

```
$records = DB::table('atble')->select('res_id',
'msg_string')->where('res_id',
$param)->whereJsonContains('ret_string->msg', ['object_key' => 'object_value'])->latest()->first();
```

also follow [WhereJsonContains](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses) proper guidelines

also you can follow this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66080731/laravel-8-x-where-json-search-in-array) for more help

This is the example it will help you.

```
$array = [0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3];

// Eloquent
PaymentTransaction::whereJsonContains('payload->ProductCode- >id',$array)->get();
```

Comment: If i want to add array in that?

Comment: @MHEMBINT i have added the array format also .