# Search in array within Json column with Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

In my Laravel project, I have a `products` table with a json column calle `data`. In the json column I have the following structure:

```
{
  "storage" : [
    {
      "stowage" : 1,
      "quantity" : 100
    },
    {
      "stowage" : 5,
      "quantity" : 500
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to search products with stowages that have less than 500 items. I know that I can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM products p WHERE 
JSON_EXTRACT( p.`data`, '$.storage[0].quantity') < 500;
```

First I would like to convert that to Laravel eloquent, something like:

```
$products = Product::where( 'data->storage[0].quantity, '<', 500 )->get();
```

I tried that one and does not work, but I would also want to search in all the stowages:

```
$products = Product::where( 'data->storage->>quantity', '<', 500 )->get();
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure of the syntax for searching all `storage` objects' `.quantity` values, but Laravel does have support for JSON where clauses: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses; might find something useful there 

Comment: I went through Laravel's JSON documentation, and it does not help with my problem. I used some of that information for other parts of my project, but the one I'm asking about here is not in any way covered by that documentation. But thanks anyway.

Comment: No problem! I was hopeful, but alas. Hopefully someone else will be able to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

We have **whereJsonContains** method for eloquent to search from json data in column..

[Search in Json column with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53641403/search-in-json-column-with-laravel)