# Search in json column not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, orm

I have one table which contains json string column ,i want to search inside the json column for that i am using whereJsonContains method but still it’s showing empty records but the data is there .did i miss anything .

`$id=98; $reqid=7; Table::whereJsonContains(“json_data->”.$id ,$reqid)->get();`

My json data is {“94”:”3”,”98”:”7”}

I was trying to fetch that column data and make it an array but it’s taking more time to execute so i want to do in query level for that i tried with whereJsonContains

Comment: I think this is the answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53641403/search-in-json-column-with-laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about **whereJsonContains** but following way will work

```
$result = Table::where(“json_data->$id” ,$reqid)->get();
dd($result);
```